# sql query Update INNER JOINED table

Tags: sql

i use INNER JOIN in my 2 tables which is GuestInfo and Reservation

```
select  RoomNo, DateStart, DateEnd, GuestFName, GuestMName, GuestLName
from GuestInfo inner join Reservation
on GuestInfo.GuestID = Reservation.GuestID
```

now, i want to update that INNER JOINED TABLE

```
update (select  RoomNo, DateStart, DateEnd, GuestFName, GuestMName, GuestLName
from GuestInfo inner join Reservation
on GuestInfo.GuestID = Reservation.GuestID) set EndDate = '1/20/2014'
where GuestFName = 'JAKE'
```

but this query is error. is this possible?

Comment: You can't update the result of an inner join.  You can only update one of the base tables.  It would greatly help if you would use aliases to show where the columns are coming from.

Comment: Also, look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql. What RDMS are you using?

Comment: What is the exact error message? And which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use something similar to this depending on your database.

SQL Server:

```
update r
set r.DateEnd = '2014-01-20' 
from Reservation r
inner join GuestInfo g
    on g.GuestID = r.GuestID 
where g.GuestFName = 'JAKE'
```

MySQL:

```
update Reservation r
inner join GuestInfo g
    on g.GuestID = r.GuestID 
set r.DateEnd = '2014-01-20' 
where g.GuestFName = 'JAKE'
```

Answer (score 2):

The following syntax should work in any database:

```
update reservation
    set enddate = '1/20/2014'
    where guestid in (select guestId from guestinfo where guestfname = 'Jake')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you can use:

```
update reservation 
set EndDate = '1/20/2014'
where GuestID in (select GuestID
     from GuestInfo inner join Reservation
     on GuestInfo.GuestID = Reservation.GuestID 
     and GuestFName = 'JAKE')
```

Comment: See the answer from Gordon Linoff, it's better than mine!

Comment: Query syntax is wrong, When you are using IN clause you cannot return more than one column in subquery